# What is Docker? Can it be a great version control?

Tags: 14.04

Wherever I go, people around me talk about Docker. They say it's revolutionary, but how is that revolutionary?

I have heard that Docker can be used as a version control even though it's not the main feature of Docker. So how great is it as a version control? Is it good enough to replace other version controls out there?

Comment: David Foerster -- Thanks for your answer. Honestly I don't know if Docker can be a nice version control either. I just saw an article of what Docker could do and one of the features was version control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isn't Docker an application container infrastructure? I read, that Docker has a kind of version control (through file system snapshots), but it's neither distributed nor has it more than merely very basic management capabilities, while Git is poorly fit for large amounts of binary data.

From my understanding:

- [Docker](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Docker_(software)) is an infrastructure to deploy and manage portable software appliances, while
- [Git](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Git_(software)) is a distributed revision control system aimed at source code or other text-oriented files.

I cannot think of a use case, where either may reasonably substitute the other, so the question “*Which of the two is better™?*” seems moot.

Comment: git now handles large and/or binary files ... see https://git-lfs.github.com/